# JDO - Persisting two entities with same key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm working on an AppEngine project and I'm using JDO on top of the AppEngine datastore for persistence. I have an entity that uses an encoded string as the key and also uses an application generated keyname (also a string). I did this because my app would frequently scoop data (potentially scooping the same thing) from the wild and attempt to persist them. In an attempt to avoid persisting several entities which essentially contain the same data, I decided to hash some properties about these data so as to get a consistent keyname (not manipulating keys directly because of entity relationships).
The problem now is that whenever I calculate my hash (keyname) and attempt to store the entity, if it already exists in the datastore, the datastore (or JDO or whoever the culprit is) silently overwrites the properties of the entity in the datastore without raising any exception. This has serious effects on the app because it overrides the timeStamps (a field) of the entities (which we use for ordering).
How best can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do get-before-set (Check and set or CAS).

CAS is a fundamental tenant of concurrency, and it's a necessary evil of parallel computing.

Gets are much cheaper than sets anyway, so it may actually save you money.

Instead of blind writing to datastore, first retrieve; if the entity doesn't exist, catch the exception and just put the entity.  If it does exist, do a deep compare before you save.  If nothing has changed, don't persist it (and save that cost).  If it has changed, choose your merge strategy however you please.  One (slightly ugly) way to maintain dated revisions is to store the previous entity as a field in the updated entity (may not work for many revisions).

But, in this case, you have to get before set.  If you don't expect many duplicates and want to be really chintzy, you can do an exists query first... Which is to do a keys-only count query on the key you want to use (costs 7x less than a full get).  If (count() == 0) then put() else getAndMaybePut() fi

The count query syntax might look slow, but from my benchmarks, it's the fastest (and cheapest) possible way to tell if an entity exists:

```
public boolean exists(Key key){
    Query q;
    if (key.getParent() == null)
      q = new Query(key.getKind());
    else
      q = new Query(key.getKind(), key.getParent());
    q.setKeysOnly();
    q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate(
      Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, FilterOperator.EQUAL, key));
    return 1 == DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().prepare(q)
      .countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));
}
```

Comment: (y) I was thinking there might be a way to do this without making a _get_ prior to the potential _put_
Also, thanks for the performance tip of key-only retrieval. I'll implement this solution then.

Comment: Yup.  I know that get-before-set seems like a waste, but it fits with the appengine / keystore paradigm of "reads are fast, writes are slow".  A key-count query is ridiculously fast, and rewards any app that can construct keys from known runtime data.  

I'll update my answer with some example code for the count query.

Comment: This actually costs more than a "full get" because the query costs one read_op plus one small_op. The setKeysOnly() is not needed because a count query sets this automatically and also does not return the keys.

Comment: I thought only queries that return objects cost a read.  You aren't looking in the entity table, just checking the number in the key table. If you returned the key instead of counting it (more work), that would constitute a small op, not a read op.

Comment: Hm.  It appears you're right.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Cost  

1 Read + 1 small.  I guess the only way to make it pay is to check if one of a set of keys exist (and even then, that might cost 1 read + 1 small per item of the IN query).

Although get() will be cheaper, it may be slower.  Of course, being able to do asynchronous get() means you can launch your request immediately, then access the session or do some other time consuming task, and check the Future after it's done, thus making effective walltime 0millis...

Comment: I just sticked with a direct key lookup using JDO's PersistenceManager#getObjectById, if it returns normally then skip, if it throws an Exception then attempt a write. I think they said somewhere in the docs that its about 5 times faster than using a Query. Do you think my approach is okay in terms of performance?

Comment: You should be just fine.  If you are only handling one object per request, you can't really avoid blocking on the get().  If you are handling more than one, look into the low-level asynchronous datastore; you can launch all gets at once, then by the time you resolve the first one, all subsequent gets will also be finished.

Comment: As for performance metrics, the only conclusive way to know is to run a test.  For that, I'd recommend a simple interface CheckExists{ boolean exists(Key key);}, and try both.  Run them in production, as dev mode results are not accurate to prod.  Generate say, 10,000 entities with known keys, then run 10,000 positive results on the keys you created, and 10,000 negative results, on keys that don't exist.  This will tell you for sure which is fastest.  Note that there is internal caching done when reusing the same keys and based on whether you use STRONG or EVENTUAL consistency.

Comment: From what I can tell, at least if you're using JDO, if you call this method twice in rapid succession, it's still possible to overwrite the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

You must do a get() to see if an entity with the same key exists before you put() the new entity.  There is no way around doing this.

You can use memcache and local "in-memory" caching to speed up your get() operation.  This may only help if you are likely to read the same information multiple times.  If not, the memcache query may actually slow down your process.

To ensure that two requests do not overwrite each other you should use a transaction (not possible with a query as suggested by Ajax unless you put all items in a single entity group which may limit your updates to 1 per second)

In pseudo code:

1. Create Key from hashing data
2. Check in-memory cache for key (use a ConcurrentHashSet of keys), return if found
3. Check MemcacheService for key, return if found
4. Start transaction
5. Get entity from datastore, return if found
6. Create entity in datastore
7. Commit transaction, return if fails due to concurrent update
8. Put Key in cache (in-memory and memcache)

Step 7 will fail if another request (thread) has already written the same key at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is that instead of saving the ID as a string either use a Long ID for your entity or you may use Key datatype, which is auto generated by appengine.

```
   @PersistenceCapable
   public class Test{
     @PrimaryKey
     @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
     private Long ID;

     // getter and setter 
   }
```

> This will return a unique value to you everytime.

Comment: the issue with this approach is that a unique key values everytime will give my app several entities that have the same data content. That was why I came up with the hashing approach in the first place.

Comment: Can you share the Entity Code here. So that I can help you with it.

Comment: You'll also want to avoid Long keys if you don't need them...  The datastore has to lock on a per-table atomic long; if you have thousands of concurrent requests creating entities of the same type with Long keys, you will notice significant latency and even errors having them generate Long keys for you (you can reserve a range of keys at once if you'd like to allocate manually; this will only lock once to get many keys).

This is also why your long keys in the same request will often be offset by multiples of 1000; each request reserves a range of 1000 keys to cut down on locking time.

Comment: Actually the data population is done by a single thread at specific intervals (a cron job) and I'm using String keys so I think I'm kind'a safe. Meanwhile, I've fixed this issue and everything works perfectly. Thanks for the performance tip you just shared, its really enlightening!